# Hosting Migration Drupal 8 Link Faliure

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, migration, hosting, drupal-8

I'm changing my hosting from a VPS server to the cloud
I've copied the files and database from the old site to the new one.

I have updated the data to access the database but there is a problem ...

on the old server the apache configuration was :
domain ... points to the /domain/www/web directory
and it worked perfectly.

On the new server the apache configuration is :
domain ... points to the /domain/public_html directory and I can't change it in the cloud apache configuration.

The website files are currently in the directory :
/domain/public_html/www/web

I need to keep the
URL = domain.com
must remain fixed and point to the directory :
/domain/public_html/www/web

If I use an .htaccess configuration, I end up with the following URL:
domain.com/www/web/index.php
the home page is displayed correctly, but as soon as I navigate the paths are broken.

Is there any special configuration I need to do in Drupal 8 or in .htaccess to tell it that

the URL = domain.com
points to the /domain/public_html/www/web directory and that when browsing the site, all links are of the type
URL = domain.com/link.php or domain.com/directory/link.php

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Help and a solution if someone has already had the problem.

Comment: _"The website files are currently in the directory : /domain/public_html/www/web"_ - why? Why don't you just upload everything that was in `/www/web` on the old system, directly into `/public_html` now ...?

Comment: I can't do this because there are private files and configuration files in the www directory that shouldn't be accessible via the web.

Comment: So those would simply go one level up then - the `public_html` directory here is the equivalent of your `web ` directory on the old system. So upload everything you had in `www/web/` to `domain/public_html/`, and the rest remaining in `www/`, goes into the `domain/` folder.